# Permutation tests and multiple testing

Tags: multiple-comparisons, random-forest, permutation-test, false-discovery-rate

I'm using permutation tests, based on **random forest** importance measures, to perform **variables selection** in my dataset. Using $99$ permutations, my permutation tests $p$-values are comprised between $0.01$ and $1$.

As I am using this procedure with more than $300$ covariates, I considered the issue of multiple testing. However, with all the $p$-value adjustment procedures I considered (BH, q-value, etc.) none of my $p$-values remained significant. Is there an easy way to deal with **multiple testing** when using **permutation tests**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to either **(a) increase the number of permutations** so the p-values won't have a lower bound as high as 0.01 (even with a single measure I'd use at least 1000 permutations!) or **(b) incorporate multiple testing correction within the permutation testing**. This can be achieved by the **Max-T** method: in each permutation, record the maximal statistic across all the 300 measures. You'll end up with a single empirical sampling distribution that describes the maximal statistic across all measures, given the null hypothesis. Then, for each measure in the unpermuted set, determine its p-value according to this distribution. The resulting 300 p-values will be already corrected for family-wise error.

Reference for the max-t/min-p method:

> Westfall, P. H., & Young, S. S. (1993). Resampling-based multiple
>   testing: Examples and methods for p-value adjustment (Vol. 279). John
>   Wiley & Sons.